# How do you debug a request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, xmlhttprequest, status

How do you debug a request?
Like the code below.
This is javascript.  And I am running through firebug.
But I never get anything on

```
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
```

To check the status.
So the call goes out.  And nothing back.
How can someone debug this?  Is there some other way to get an error code?

thank you

```
function codeAddress() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    var address = document.getElementById("storeAddress").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        storeGeo = results[0].geometry.location;

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have a look on the network panel, and potentually the error console.

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Chrome Network Tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)

Comment: also, you could place breakpoints and step through your code via javascript debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can check with wireshark if the request is send to the interface or you can append the GET-URL string XESSION_XDEBUG_START to the url.